# Material angular 15 checkbox, replace state with two svgs

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible to replace the checked not-checked states of the checkbox with two svgs below?

[image]

I was able to do it with just input, but is it possible to do with mat-checkbox?

```
<div style="width: 30%; padding-left: 35px;padding-bottom: 10px;">
      <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing" /><label for="thing"></label>
    </div>

input[type=checkbox]+label {
  background:
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path d='YOUR SVG'/></svg>");
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  background:
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path d='YOUR SVG'/></svg>");
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```